# Converting nested JSON to csv in GO

Tags: json, csv, go

I have an example json, the field names aren't really important but the nested values and the data types of some fields are. I understand that in go you have to make sure that when you write to a csv, the data is a string data type when you use csv.Writer. My question is, whats the proper way of writing the nested values, and is there an efficient way to convert all non-string values by iterating through the overall json?

```
`{
  "name":"Name1",
  "id": 2,
  "jobs":{
      "job1":"somejob",
      "job2":"somejob2"
   },
  "prevIds":{
      "id1": 100,
      "id2": 102
  }
}`
```

Is the example json

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: I don't really have an expected output, but want to see what it would look like with a nested json

Comment: You have written the nested JSON there, so I guess that's your answer? You seem to want to "convert JSON to csv" but that's not descriptive enough. How do you want your own simple example to look as a csv?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A working example is below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func decodeJson(m map[string]interface{}) []string {
    values := make([]string, 0, len(m))
    for _, v := range m {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            for _, value := range decodeJson(vv) {
                values = append(values, value)
            }
        case string:
            values = append(values, vv)
        case float64:
            values = append(values, strconv.FormatFloat(vv, 'f', -1, 64))
        case []interface{}:
            // Arrays aren't currently handled, since you haven't indicated that we should
            // and it's non-trivial to do so.
        case bool:
            values = append(values, strconv.FormatBool(vv))
        case nil:
            values = append(values, "nil")
        }
    }
    return values
}

func main() {
    var d interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(exampleJSON, &d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to unmarshal")
    }
    values := decodeJson(d.(map[string]interface{}))
    fmt.Println(values)

    f, err := os.Create("outputfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create outputfile.csv")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    if err := w.Write(values); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to write to file")
    }
    w.Flush()
    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to flush outputfile.csv")
    }
}

var exampleJSON []byte = []byte(`{
  "name":"Name1",
  "id": 2,
  "jobs":{
      "job1":"somejob",
      "job2":"somejob2"
   },
  "prevIds":{
      "id1": 100,
      "id2": 102
  }
}`)
```

This works by decoding the arbitrary JSON as shown in [this goblog post](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) then iterating and handling each possible type by converting it to string in the usual way. If you come across a `map[string]interface{}`, then you're recursing to get the next set of data.

Once you've got a `[]string`, you can pass it to your `csv.Writer` to write out however you like. In this case the output is

```
Name1,2,somejob,somejob2,100,102
```

Comment: AH I see! Thank you, this is very informative!
Yeah, I wasn't sure how to handle a nested object.